# Why doesen't prompt() inside a for loop in javascript work for my code below?

Tags: javascript

Why doesen't prompt() inside a for loop in javascript work for my code below?

```
var P = [];
for(i=0;i++;i<10)
{
    var g=parseInt(prompt("What is the money you paid in"+i+ "month?"));
    P[i]=g;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop is wrong. It should be

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
```

You mixed up the second and third parts. The condition comes second, the variable increment comes last.

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the parts of the `for` loop. The condition is second:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

Also don't forget `var`, and `parseInt(x, 10)` prevents some weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is formatted incorrectly, a for loop should be:

```
for ( state; condition; action )
```

So, given your case, the correct loop is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```